# Differential operator $\nabla V(x)\cdot \nabla_v$ makes distributional sense?

Tags: distribution-theory

In Villani's *Hypocoercivity*, there is a statement as follows,

> ... even if $\nabla V$ is only continuous: the differential operator $\nabla V(x)\cdot \nabla_v$ makes distributional sense

I don't understand how $\nabla V(x)\cdot \nabla_v$ makes distributional sense even though $\nabla V$ is only continuous. Shouldn't $\nabla V(x) \in C^\infty$ if it would make distributional sense? Any help or any reference would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It means $V$ is to be understood as a Schwartz distribution and the derivatives in the gradient are the derivatives from elementary calculus but the generalization in the context of the the theory of Schwartz distributions. Now what that is a long story. You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics) or here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/245c-notes-3-distributions/

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thanks for your answer, but the book says $\nabla V$ is only continuous. If $V$ is a Schwartz distribution, then $\nabla V$ is not just continuous generally, isn't it? Please help me to understand it.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I know the basic distribution theory. So, if $\nabla V(x) \cdot \nabla_v$ is to make distribution sense, $\nabla V(x) $ should be in $ C^\infty$ since for any distribution $u$, $\nabla_v u$ make sense, but if $\nabla V(x) $ is only continuous, $\nabla V(x) \cdot \nabla_v u$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I see two possible explanations: 1) the operator is map from $\mathscr{D}$ (test functions) to $\mathscr{D}'$ (distributions), in which case it makes sense, and also corresponds to a distribution on the product space by the nuclear theorem, or 2) the author is using a hack which is very specific to the situation considered and  goes beyond the multiplication of a distribution by a smooth function (charted territory). To know for sure, one needs the context of the statement and the book which I don't have.